# .htaccess the requested url /public/index was not found on this server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, digital-ocean

Hello there i just finished setting up my server and all my code files but im having a problem. Whenever i go to https://www.frindse.com/index it gives me a error that says that the /public/index file is not found.

The way my site is setup is all the requests goes to the public folder which holds my index.php file that routes all of my pages. Not on my local server everything works flawlessly but on my digitalocean server whenever i go to the index page it doesn't works. But if i go to https://www.frindse.com/login the pages loads perfectly. So this is how my .htaccess file looks in my public folder which routes all my pages and requests:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Also here is the .htaccess file thats in the root of my website. It routes all the calls to the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Also keep in mind that i have mod_rewrite activated on my server and also i have set AllowOverride set to All in my digitaloceans erver.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a rewritebase to your .htaccess in public folder. And turn off multiviews for good measure.

```
Options -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Actually, why do you even need an .htaccess file in public folder? Just route the request directly to the index file like this *.htaccess file in your root* and remove the the one in public folder.

```
    Options -MultiViews
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

    </IfModule>
```

Comment: it seemed to have done the trick but not its giving me a too many redirects error. On my localhost server it works fine with no redirects. But oddly it gives my a too many  redirects error